# nosuchElementException issue using iterator

Tags: java, iterator, nosuchelementexception

I have this printStackTrace when my program run into the for of a Collection

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No next element
at positionalList.NodePositionList$IteratorList.next(NodePositionList.java:177)
at positionalList.NodePositionList$IteratorList.next(NodePositionList.java:1)
at positionalList.Ricerca.DFS(Ricerca.java:130)
at positionalList.Ricerca.main(Ricerca.java:291)
```

I wrote my own Iterator, and i used a head node and a tail node (with their Key set to null) to find easily the beginning and the end of the list. This class is inside the NodePositionList class, in the package positionalList

```
private class IteratorList<T> implements Iterator<K> {
    protected NodePositionList<K> npl;
    protected Position<K> p;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public IteratorList(NodePositionList<K> n) {
            this.npl = n;
            Position<K> p = (npl.isEmpty()) ? null : npl.first();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return  p != tail;
    }

    @Override
    public K next() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (p == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No next element");
        }
        K toReturn = p.element();
        p = (p == npl.getTail()) ? null : npl.next(p);
        return toReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (p == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No element to remove");
        }
        p = npl.remove(p);  
    }
}
```

I called it with this code, that belongs to the package "algoritmo".

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void DFS(TDAGraph<T> g) {
    for (Vertex<T> v: g.vertices()) {
        if (v.getColor() == VertexColor.WHITE) {
            DFS_visit(g,v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
public IteratorList(NodePositionList<K> n){
    this.npl = n;
    Position<K> p = (npl.isEmpty()) ? null : npl.first();
}
```

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `p` by creating a local variable with the same name. That "forces" the instance variable `p` to stay `null`. If you call `next()` for the first time, the check for `null` will be true, which triggers your `NoSuchElementException`.

Either remove the type or add `this` to it:

```
public IteratorList(NodePositionList<K> n){
    this.npl = n;
    p = (npl.isEmpty()) ? null : npl.first();
}
```

Or:

```
public IteratorList(NodePositionList<K> n){
    this.npl = n;
    this.p = (npl.isEmpty()) ? null : npl.first();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructor will be like this

```
public IteratorList(NodePositionList<K> n){
            this.npl = n;
            this.p = (npl.isEmpty()) ? null : npl.first();
    }
```